# Restarted instance causes cloudflare error 521

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger, cloudflare

I had a running Rails application on an Amazon instance via Passenger + Nginx with Cloudflare enabled.

I restarted my instance on the online Amazon console by right-clicking "Reboot". Now whenever I visit my site using the DNS, it gives me a 521 error stating that the web server is down. However, if I visit through the ip address directly, it works.

I read in a few places that Cloudflare may have been blocked. Where can I identify what is blocking CloudFlare's requests?

Answer (score 1):

That does sound like something at Amazon is blocking our IPs. Have you reached out to them? [CloudFlare's IP ranges](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips).